# Magento2 Swagger generated php client broken

Tags: php, code-generation, swagger, magento2, client-library

I've generated a PHP client library for Magento2 using [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen). I'm able to connect to Magento and just trying some methods to see how usable the generated client is. It seems like I'm either missing something or maybe the swagger spec published by Magento is not quite there yet.

In particular, invoking the various list operations seems to be marginalized by design, and broken by nature in the generated swagger client. Take for example the operation to list products, [/V1/products](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#resource_catalogProductRepositoryV1). Swagger UI indicates this can be parameterized with GET parameters (and in fact seems you must - when I try calling it with no parameters Magento returns an HTTP 400). Here's the sample generated code from the Markdown Swagger generated along with the client library

```
try { 
    $result = $api_instance->catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListGet(
        $search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_field, 
        $search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_value, 
        $search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_condition_type, 
        $search_criteria_sort_orders_field,  
        $search_criteria_sort_orders_direction, $search_criteria_page_size, 
        $search_criteria_current_page);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo
        'Exception when calling CatalogProductRepositoryVApi->catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListGet: ',
        $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

The first thing I notice is that these parameters only allow a single entry for each field, when the API actually allows you to define multiple *filter_groups*, multiple *filters* per *filter_group* etc. This [great blog post](https://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/) helped me understand how the API is *supposed* to work.

Stepping back though, and supposing a limit of one *filter_group* and one *filter* for that group are acceptable and just trying to use the generated client on faith, I tried to put together a simple call

```
// Fetch all products with a contrived like query
$oMageClient = new Swagger\Client\Api\CatalogProductRepositoryVApi($oApiClient);
$result      = $oMageClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListGet('name', '%', 'like');
```

Magento complains with an HTTP 400, and it's because of the generated client's request params:

```
searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][value]=%&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][conditionType]=like
```

What it's done is broken up the parameters into different *filter_groups*... Sure enough when I look at the generated `Swagger\Client\Api\CatalogProductRepositoryVApi:: catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListGetWithHttpInfo` method I find the culprit where the query params are set. By changing

```
// query params
if ($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_field !== null) {
    $queryParams['searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field]'] = $this->apiClient->getSerializer()->toQueryValue($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_field);
}// query params
if ($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_value !== null) {
    $queryParams['searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][value]'] = $this->apiClient->getSerializer()->toQueryValue($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_value);
}// query params
if ($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_condition_type !== null) {
    $queryParams['searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][conditionType]'] = $this->apiClient->getSerializer()->toQueryValue($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_condition_type);
}
```

to

```
// query params
if ($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_field !== null) {
    $queryParams['searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]'] = $this->apiClient->getSerializer()->toQueryValue($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_field);
}// query params
if ($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_value !== null) {
    $queryParams['searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]'] = $this->apiClient->getSerializer()->toQueryValue($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_value);
}// query params
if ($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_condition_type !== null) {
    $queryParams['searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]'] = $this->apiClient->getSerializer()->toQueryValue($search_criteria_filter_groups_filters_condition_type);
}
```

I'm able to get a response back from Magento. So I have a couple of questions

So is there an issue with the JSON Magento is publishing causing the generated Swagger code to be buggy? Or is there some other step I've messed up in generating the client?

It feels like something's not right, because if you look at the [blog article](https://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/) and the generated Swagger documentation, Swagger is suggesting the *filter_groups* parameter is a string, when really it should be an array of objects.

Comment: To you have the Magento OpenAPI/Swagger spec that you can share with us? You can also open a ticket via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have a local Magento2 install where I noticed this, but just confirmed the case is true with the [public schema](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/schemas/latest-2.0.schema.json) too. I'll go ahead and file a bug report.

Comment: I ended up opening two tickets as there was another issue I saw :) 1. [The ticket for the bug described here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2624). [A ticket for a smaller issue (syntax error)](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2625). I would have opened a ticket sooner, but this is my first experience with Swagger.